# How do I call all the a's in main method?

Tags: java, variables, constructor, this, instance

> I want to call all the a's in the main and print the variables that contains

```
package testj;
class Test{
    int a = 3;//------------------------------- a - 3
    String b;
    float f;

    Test(int a){
        this.a = a;
        a = 4;//------------------------------- a - 4
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;//--------------------------- a - 1
        System.out.println(a); 
        Test t = new Test(2);//---------------- a - 2
        System.out.println(t.a);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "calling" a variable? And to print a variable, you have to add a print statement in the scope where it is declared. Some of these are local variables/parameters, so they are not accessible outside of the method in which they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test{
    int a = 3;//------------------------------- a - 3
    String b;
    float f;

    Test(int a){
        System.out.println(this.a);
        this.a = a;
        a = 4;//------------------------------- a - 4
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;//--------------------------- a - 1
        System.out.println(a);//prints 1
        Test t = new Test(2);//prints 3 & 4
        System.out.println(t.a);//prints 2
    }
}
```

You cannot directly access global variables that are shadowed by local variables.

Comment: It's not the same `a` accessed through `t.a`?

Comment: @PawełDyl, thanks for the correction, edited and tested this time.